# swapping between members of a string array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to remove the i-th member of a string array, and bring every member which comes after it one place prior (the i+1-th member to i and so on). I came up with the following code:

```
    for (int j = i; j < arrSize - 1; j++) {
        strcpy(members[j],members[j+1]);
    }
    free(members[arrSize-1]);
```

But that got me thinking that it might be wrong. For example, if the i-th place member contains the name "John", while the (i+1)-th place members contains the name "Joshua", which means each string is in a different length, would there be any memory leaks or any problem? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The definiton of members:

```
members = malloc(maxMembersNum * sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: and what exactly is a `string array`? I mean, show us the definition of `members`.

Comment: how do you allocate for `members`?

Comment: There's no way to answer this question without seeing the declaration of `members` and how it's built. C has multiple ways to do this.

Comment: `free(members[i]);for (int j = i; j < arrSize - 1; j++) { members[j] = members[j+1]; }`
    `

Comment: If `arrSize` is actually a size then the code has a buffer overflow on the last iteration of the for-loop, and it should be `arrSize-2` in the for-loop

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copy the contents of the strings, why not move the pointers around?  That is:

```
for (int j = i; j < arrSize - 1; j++) {
    char *temp = members[j];
    members[j] = members[j+1];
    members[j+1] = temp;
}
free(members[arrSize-1]);
```

Comment: That only works if there are pointers. OP has not shown us that.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker They must be, else the call to `strcpy` and the `free` at the end make no sense.

Comment: Actually, there's no possible code in which they both make sense. Either it's an array of pointers, in which case he needs the free but not the strcpy, or it's a 2d char array, in which case he needs strcpy but not free.

Comment: To expand on this answer, if the order of the strings in members does not matter, then you can also perform a swap with `i` and the last member only, rather than swapping all items after `i`. Also, if `arrSize` is actually a size then the code has a buffer overflow, and it should be `arrSize-2` in the for-loop.

Comment: The order does matter. In addition, why is there a buffer over follow? for j =arrSize-2 I'll access arrSize-2 and arrSize-1.

Comment: Also, for "delete" to be meaningful, either arrSize has to change, or the tail of the array has to be filled with NULL pointers.

Comment: And finally, even after being fixed, this answer does 3*N moves where only N moves are necessary, so it's slow.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments said, the definition of members determines the outcome of the function.

If it is:

`char* members[];`

then it is an array of pointers, using strcpy will overwrite memory and you will eventually crash unless all of those buffers are allocated and the same size.  In this case, you can just copy the pointers with

```
members[j] = members[j+1]
```

if it is:

`std::string members[];`

then you can treat it as a normal array and dispense with strcpy and free (just use =).

if it is:

char members[80][80]; // fixed size pre-allocated buffer

then your code will work, but free will not.

Comment: `std::string members[];`...in `C`? how?

Comment: Sorry, that would require C++.  I missed the OP's restriction to 'C' only.

Answer (score -1):

It would be simpler if lines and arrSize were members of a structure that you could pass in as a unit, but absent that:

```
void remove_by_index(char **lines, int line, int *arrSize) {
    if (line >= *arrSize) return;
    *arrSize -= 1;

    if (lines[line]) free(lines[line]);
    memmove(lines + line, lines + line + 1, ((*arrSize - line) * sizeof(char *)));
    lines[*arrSize] = NULL;
}
```

Strictly speaking, either `arrSize` has to change to reflect deletion, or else the deleted cell has to be marked with NULL, but it's not necessary to do both as I have done here (though it's not a bad idea).

Also note that this will fail if two members of the array point to the same string, as will the other answers here--for that you'll need a more complex data structure.

Comment: `free(lines[*arrSize]);` is wrong. `free` should apply to `lines[line]` before `memmove`.